# How to add an iFrame page Tab application to an Application profile page?

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-iframe

I've been trying to set up my Facebook Application Profile Page by adding an iFrame tab to it. Seeing as this is similar to the process of adding an iFrame tab to a Fan Page, I going through the same process, to no avail.

In order to add an iFrame tab to a Fan Page, one is required to create a Facebook iFrame Page Tab Application (process described here: http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-an-iframe-application-to-your-facebook-fan-page-fall-2012/), and then browse to the newly created app's page, click the 'Add to My Page' link and select the page to which they want to add the iFrame Page Tab Application.

Now, if I want to do the same thing, but instead of adding the iFrame Page Tab Application to a Fan Page, add it to an Application Profile Page, then that's impossible because, apparently, Application Profile Pages don't appear in the window where you'd select the page you want to add the tab to. I've seen other applications that have done it, and have tried many approaches, none of which seem to work.

Any ideas?

Ultimately, my goal is to create a tab in my Application Profile Page, with my own content (which is basically just a picture with a link on it). Tried using the FBML app that Facebook provides but the problem with that is that they don't let you customize the icon to the left of the tab when using the FBML app, and using the iFrame Page Tab Application (as described above) is a workaround, but then I can't add it to my App profile page :\

Thanks